# About the burr distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In my papers the probability density for a burr distribution is given as

$$f(x) = \frac{\gamma \tau \alpha^{\gamma}x^{\tau - 1} }{(\alpha + x^{\tau})^{\gamma + 1}}$$

however i have encountered this definition

$$f(x \mid \alpha,c , k)= \frac{\frac{kc}{\alpha}(\frac{x}{\alpha})^{c-1} }{ \Big( 1+ (\frac{x}{\alpha})^c  \Big)^{k+1}}$$

Iam trying to write the former definition as the first one i gave above , but setting $\tau =c$ and $\gamma = k$  won't do it. anyone?

what Iam trying to say that if it is possible to do this?

$$\frac{\frac{kc}{\alpha}(\frac{x}{\alpha})^{c-1} }{ \Big( 1+ (\frac{x}{\alpha})^c  \Big)^{k+1}} =\frac{\frac{\gamma \tau}{\alpha} (\frac{x}{\alpha})^{\tau-1}}{(1 + (\frac{x}{\alpha})^{\tau})^{\gamma+1}} = \frac{\gamma \tau x^{\tau-1}}{\alpha^{\tau} (1 + (\frac{x}{\alpha})^{\tau})^{\gamma+1}} = \frac{\gamma \tau x^{\tau-1}}{\alpha^{\tau} (1 + (\frac{x}{\alpha})^{\tau}) (1 + (\frac{x}{\alpha})^{\tau})^{\gamma}}  = \cdots \text{??} \cdots  = \frac{\gamma \tau \alpha^{\gamma}x^{\tau - 1} }{(\alpha + x^{\tau})^{\gamma + 1}}$$

Comment: IIRC, there are a dozen or so "burr" distributions, so these may in fact refer to differing types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct relationship between the two is obtained as follows:  in the second parametrization, let $$\alpha \to \alpha^{1/\tau}, \quad c \to \tau, \quad k \to \gamma.$$

Comment: thanks @heropup i figured that out just right now also !!!